# Subtract dates row by row if the ids are the same

Tags: pandas

I'd like to subtract dates if the next row's id is the same. I'm able to subtract dates, but stuck on creating the condition to check if the next row has the same id.

```
d = {'date':['2021-01', '2020-01', '2020-05', '2021-01'], 'id':['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
date    id
2021-01 a
2020-01 a
2020-05 b
2021-01 b
```

My code

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['id', 'date'])
df['date_diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']) - pd.to_datetime(df['date'].shift())
```

result

```
date    id  date_diff
2020-01 a   NaT
2021-01 a   366 days
2020-05 b   -245 days
2021-01 b   245 days
```

Expected result should as below, which the dates only be subtracted when the ids are the same.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain with `groupby`

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date_diff'] = df.groupby('id')['date'].diff()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date_diff']=df.groupby('id')['date'].diff()
```